# Could not find datasource JNDI

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy an application server on my machine, but I have been facing some problems.

I am trying to migrate an websphere application to a weblogic one.

After some changes on code I got this:

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
        <description>
        </description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/pds</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>
    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>java:hibernate/PSessionFactory</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>org.hibernate.SessionFactory</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
```

weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app 
http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<context-root>P</context-root>
<resource-description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/pds</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>pds</jndi-name>
</resource-description>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

On administration console, the data source seems to be right configured, because I already tested it.

When I try to launch the app, I see this in logs:

```
INFO: JNDI InitialContext properties:{}
mai 06, 2019 11:28:59 AM org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider configure
SEVERE: Could not find datasource: java:comp/env/dsp
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/dsp in /app/webapp/P/1500078469.; remaining name 'comp/env/dsp'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1292)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.lookup(ApplicationNamingNode.java:144)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:307)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:434)
    at weblogic.jndi.factories.java.ReadOnlyContextWrapper.lookup(ReadOnlyContextWrapper.java:45)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.AbstractURLContext.lookup(AbstractURLContext.java:130)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2119)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2115)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1339)
    at picage.utils.HibernatePlugIn.initHibernate(HibernatePlugIn.java:119)
    at picage.utils.HibernatePlugIn.init(HibernatePlugIn.java:96)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:871)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:359)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:343)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:294)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:99)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:87)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:31)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:673)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:612)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.getServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:414)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:304)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at picage.utils.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at picage.utils.filters.PostDataInterceptor.doFilter(PostDataInterceptor.java:29)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at picage.utils.filters.EncondingFilter.doFilter(EncondingFilter.java:18)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="java:hibernate/PSessionFactory">

        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/dsp</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">picage.utils.PlatformOracleDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.order_updates">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name">PICAGESessionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup</property>
        <property name="SetBigStringTryClob">true</property>

        <!-- Para remover quando for para producao -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">false</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Share and check your hibernate configuration. Hibernate seems to be looking for a datasource with jndi name "dsp".

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin updated :)

Comment: I confirm, Hibernate is looking for a datasource with jndi name "dsp" and the one configured in weblogic.xml has for jndi name jdbc/pds. That does not match.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin changed weblogic.xml to <res-ref-name>jdbc/dsp</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>dsp</jndi-name>
And still has the same error on log

Comment: hibernate is looking for dsp not jdbc/dsp

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin <res-ref-name>dsp</res-ref-name>, still got the same error.

Comment: please share your datasource configuration from the domain.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin https://imgur.com/bfiIKmz
Do you need some more information?

Comment: correct your weblogic.xml file :  
    <res-ref-name>dsp</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/pds</jndi-name>  
and your web.xml file : 
<res-ref-name>dsp</res-ref-name>

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin I think it resolved the issue. I got now a different error, although I think I can handle it :)